# Save Tinymce Raw Html in Laravel 4

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, laravel, tinymce

Im trying to save tinymce html source using ajax in laravel 4, But laravel 4, strip all tags when getting from Input from controller..

Example:
From ajax: my post data:

```
var form = {id: 1,
           html: '<p>Save to Database</p>'};
```

Then from Laravel 4 controller..

when i log:

```
Input::get('html');
```

Laravel strip all html tags automatically.. 
and the output is: "Save to Database"

instead of this:

```
<p>Save to Database</p>
```

How can i get the Input as raw html data.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but it's not true (I've checked it in Laravel 4.2.9 using standard forms). When you put html tags both in textarea and input text when using `Input::get('fieldname');` you get input with html tags.

You need to make sure that you are checking it in good way, for example saving `Input::get('html')` to file. If it's still without html tags, you could change method to post (in jQuery `type: "POST"`) and recheck it again.